# Writing literal "#1" into an auxiliary file from a command with arguments

Tags: macros, auxiliary-files

I am trying to write into an auxiliary file from a command with one argument. The written text is another `\createcommand` with one argument too. When I use "`#1`" the argument of meta-command is expanded. It's ok. The problem is how to literally write "`#1`" referencing the argument of command created in the auxiliary file. I tried `\#1`, `^^23 1` and `\noexpand#1`, but it didn't work.

This is my simplified example. The problem is the last `#1`. In this case I used "`\\#1`", but this adds an undesirable slash.

```
\newcommand{\writeChapterCounter}[1]{

     \immediate\write\preludeauxfile{
        \noexpand\newcommand{\csname linktopage#1\endcsname}[1]{
            \noexpand\hyperlink{topofpage.\noexpand\arabic{ch#1}}
            {\#1 }
        } 
     }
}
```

Using `\writeChapterCounter{ChapToc}`
 it produces:

```
 \newcommand {\linktopageChapToc }[1]{ \hyperlink {topofpage.\arabic{chChapToc}} {\#1 } }
```

Thanks!

Comment: unrelated to `#` question, but you are missing a lot of `%` at ends of lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `\string#` in the `\write`  but to refer to `#` in the body of a definition you need `##` so

```
\string##
```

Answer (score 5):

- There is no need to write `#1` at all, because the argument of the new defined macro gets at the end of the definition text as last argument of `\hyperlink`. Then the new command can be defined without arguments and the argument in the input is later taken by `\hyperlink` directly.
- There are lots of (unwanted) spaces by line ends.
- I have added `\expandafter\noexpand` before the new command `\csname ...\endcsname`. It does not change the behavior, if the new command is undefined, because `\csname` automatically assigns it the meaning of `\relax`, which is not further expanded. But if the command is defined
  and can be expanded, the expansion would be written into the file, probably confusing `\newcommand`.

Code:

```
\newcommand{\writeChapterCounter}[1]{%
  \immediate\write\preludeauxfile{%
    \noexpand\newcommand{%
      \expandafter\noexpand\csname linktopage#1\endcsname
    }{%
      \noexpand\hyperlink{topofpage.\noexpand\arabic{ch#1}}%
    }%
  }%
}
```

Then `\writeChapterCounter{ChapToc}` will produce:

```
\newcommand {\linktocpageChapToc }{\hyperlink {topofpage.\arabic {chChapToc}}}
```

And `\linktocpageChapToc{foobar}` will expand to

```
\hyperlink {topofpage.\arabic {chChapToc}}{foobar}
```